# XAML file cannot create an instance object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

In an attempt to create an authentication dialog without modifying the inner workings of mahapps metro.

I created the dialog window based on [MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.InputDialog](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/Dialogs/InputDialog.xaml) but get an error: "Exception: Cannot create an instance of "BaseMetroDialog"."

The XAML file is as follows:

```
<Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                         xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                         x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.InputDialog"
                         Loaded="Dialog_Loaded">
    <Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog.DialogBody>
        <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"
                               MinHeight="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       Margin="0 5 0 0"
                       FontSize="15"
                       Text="{Binding Message, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Dialogs:InputDialog, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Dialogs:InputDialog, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                     Margin="0 5 0 0"
                     FontSize="15"
                     x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                     Text="{Binding Input, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Dialogs:InputDialog, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Dialogs:InputDialog, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Height="85">
                <Button x:Name="PART_AffirmativeButton"
                        Height="35"
                        MinWidth="80"
                        Style="{DynamicResource AccentedDialogSquareButton}"
                        Content="{Binding AffirmativeButtonText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Dialogs:InputDialog, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Margin="0 0 5 0" />
                <Button x:Name="PART_NegativeButton"
                        Height="35"
                        MinWidth="80"
                        Content="{Binding NegativeButtonText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Dialogs:InputDialog, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Margin="5 0 5 0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog.DialogBody>
</Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog>
```

Here is the output from the error:

```
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderOperations.InstantiateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.WpfPlatform.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.CreateInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode)

InnerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
```

Comment: That error is of no help to anyone. You need to find out what the inner `Exception` is... that will tell you the actual problem.

Comment: That is why I am here. How can I debug XAML files?

Comment: You should have been presented with a popup dialog when your `Exception` occurred. There should have been a *View details* link on that popup dialog. Clicking it will open another `Exception` dialog with more information about the error and in particular, the inner `Exception`.